# Use Multi processing for NetfilterQueue delay function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, netfilter

I am unable to use Multiprocessing with Netfilter queue. Code and errors are as below:

ERROR:
TypeError: print_and_accept() missing 1 required argument: 'pkt'

````
nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()

nfqueue.bind(1, print_and_accept)

try:

nfqueue.run()

except KeyboardInterrupt:

print('')

global a

time.sleep(ransecs)#ADD DELAY calculated by delay_calc()

print(pkt)

pkt.accept()

#delay_calc()

nfqueue.unbind()

p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_and_accept())

if __name__ == '__main__':

p2.start()```
````

Comment: Please edit you question to use code blocks (surround your code in triple backticks: ```). I really helps for copy-pasting and knowing where indents need to be.

Comment: I already did that. Let me try again.

Comment: @CmdCoder858 I think I have got it right now. Can you assist with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The multiprocessing library gives this example:

```
p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
```

Because of the way the Process class is formatted, you must change your multiprocessing line to:

```
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_and_accept, args=('args',))
```

The problem arises from putting the brackets after the function reference, which calls the function and causes the error. Removing these and adding arguments as required (in the form of a tuple) should fix your problem.

Comment any questions down below.